# How to mirror two external screens at a Thinkpad X1 2015?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, lenovo, thinkpad

My setup looks like this:

- Lenovo X1 2015
- Two external screens attached
- Running Ubuntu 15.04

> **What I want:** Close the laptop lid and mirror both screens, so **not
>   extending them** but let them **display the same content**.
>
> **What happens now:** When I click "mirror" in the display settings, the internal display
>   and one external gets mirrored, and the second external display stays
>   black.

**Who can help? What do I have to do to mirror two external monitors?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself. Here are the steps:

1. Open the notebook lid
2. Attach the external two screens
3. Go to the Display settings in the System Settings
4. Deactivate the internal screen (but leave it physically open)
5. install `xandr` (`sudo apt-get install xandr`)
6. Go to the terminal and list all the available monitors. Therefore, just  execute `xandr`
7. Now execute following command and replace the output-type with yours:

   ```
   xrandr --output DP2-1 --same-as DP2-2
   ```

The last command, `xrandr --same-as` will let you mirror whatever monitors you wish.